# Abstract algebra with matrices question, proving h is bijective in h(X) = AX

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

Let M be the set of all 2 × 2 matrices with real coefficients. Define a mapping
h : M → M by h(X) = AX, where

A =

```
  ⎡3  1⎤

  ⎣5  2⎦
```

X =

```
  ⎡a  b⎤

  ⎣c  d⎦
```

for any a, b, c, d ∈ R. Show that h is bijective, and find the inverse mapping of h, i.e. h^-1.

I am not sure on how to show h is bijective, is h bijective if and only if the determinant of matrix AX is non-zero?

Is h equals to the matrix A or just another 2 by 2 matrix? How to find h?

Thank you!

Comment: $AX=Y$ has a unique solution $X(=A^{-1}Y)$ for any $Y$ since $A$ is invertible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $B=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}2&-1\\-5&3\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, then $B=A^{-1}$. Now, if you define $f(X)=BX$, then, for any $2\times2$ matrix $X$, you have $f\bigl(h(X)\bigr)=h\bigl(f(X)\bigr)=X$. So, $h$ has an inverse (which is $f$), and therefore it is a bijection.

Comment: So, if I found an inverse for h, namely f in your proof, does it implies that I had already proved that f is bijective?

Comment: It proves that $h$ is bijective. Of course, $f$ is bijective too.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!